# PHP Form mail redirecting page not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email, phpmailer

The form works and I get the email but when you click submit it won't take you to the thank you page, it gives me the following error message:

```
Error 404 - Not Found

The document you are looking for may have been removed or re-named.
Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.
```

This is the code for the form:

```html
<section class="contactForm">
  <h1><strong>Contact Andrea</strong></h1>
  <form action="http://ddion.com/webcert_s17/andreas/DW_FINAL/formmail.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" required class="formStyle" id="name" form="form1">
    <br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" required class="formStyle" id="email" form="form1">
    <br>
    <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
    <textarea name="comments" cols="5" required class="formStyle" id="comments" form="form1"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="formStyle" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    
  </form>
</section>
```

This is the PHP

---

```
<?php
  $name=addslashes($_POST['name']);
  $email=addslashes($_POST['email']);
  $comments=addslashes($_POST['comments']);

 // you can specify which email you want your contact form to be emailed to here

  $toemail = "anlsimental@gmail.com";
  $subject = "from AndreaSimentalPhotogragy.com";

  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
            ."From: \"".$name."\" <".$email.">\n"
            ."Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

  $body = "Name: ".$name."<br>\n"
            ."Email: ".$email."<br>\n"
            ."Comments:<br>\n"
            .$comments;

  if (!ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$", $email))
  {
    echo "That is not a valid email address.  Please return to the"
           ." previous page and try again.";
    exit;
  }

    mail($toemail, $subject, $body, $headers);
    echo "Thanks for submitting your comments";
?>
```

My thankyou.html is located next to the php. But somehow doesn't work... Any ideas why?

Comment: Open F12 on your browser.  Turn on logging.  Keep logs between pages.  What page are you navigating to that results in a 404?  What is the thank you page?  What is the difference between them?

Comment: where have you written code for redirecting to thank you page?

Comment: Why is your thank you file `.. DW_FINAL/0;URL=thankyou.html`? Shouldn't it just be `...DW_FINAL/thankyou.html` ?

Comment: Warning: ereg function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: Echoing anything will prevent redirects from working. You need to output a `Location` header instead of the echo output.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is redirect to http://ddion.com/webcert_s17/andreas/DW_FINAL/thankyou.html instead of http://ddion.com/webcert_s17/andreas/DW_FINAL/0;URL=thankyou.html. Fix it by removing the preceding `0;URL=` from the filename in the URL.

Comment: I removed the 0;URL=  but now it just sends me to a blank page thanks for your comments.

<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="thankyou.html">
<title>Email Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  $name=addslashes($_POST['name']);
  $email=addslashes($_POST['email']);
  $comments=addslashes($_POST['comments']);

 // you can specify which email you want your contact form to be emailed to here

  $toemail = "anlsimental@gmail.com";
  $subject = "from AndreaSimentalPhotogragy.com";

Answer (score 0):

The `deprecated ereg()` function to `preg_match()`

Use this

**`preg_match()`**

Comment: This may be true, but it's not an answer. Wait until you have comment privileges.